# PHP form submit button but not leave page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a button that links to a php file that tracks user's email when clicked, but I don't want the user to leave the page when button is clicked, I just want to change button's value. 
This is the html of the form.

```
<form action="mysql-query.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit" value="Press here" id="test"  onclick="Press()">
</form>
```

And this is the script that handles the form:

```
<script>
function Press() {
   var test= document.getElementById("test");
   test.value="Thank you";
localStorage.value=("ok");
}
</script>
```

I put the display:none; because I don't want to display anything but the button and have a way to connect with my php file.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ajax:

html:

```
<form action="mysql-query.php" method="post" onsubmit="return Press(this)">
<input type="text" name="email" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit" value="Press here" id="test">
</form>
```

js:

```
function Press(form) {
   $.post($(form).attr('action'), function() {
       var test= document.getElementById("test");
       test.value="Thank you";
       localStorage.value=("ok");
   });
   return false; // prevent submitting the form
}
```

or better bind submit event using jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   $.post($(this).attr('action'), function() {
       var test= document.getElementById("test");
       test.value="Thank you";
       localStorage.value=("ok");
   });
   return false; // prevent submitting the form
});
```

Comment: thank you I used your first solution and it works perfectly!now I can focus better on my php file!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<form action="javascript:void()">
```

Ok, this thing prevents the form from sending the data anywhere, unless you use "onclick" event on the submit button.

Comment: I still want to link to the php file. You can do that and have a javascript void function?

Comment: You then need to use AJAX. I gave you link to w3schools section about AJAX in the other post

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11430379)

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is remove the type="submit" on the button and replace it with type="button". Next you can do an ajax call to your php and do your magic.

Comment: The ajax call is a next step or a different way to achieve that? Also can you post me some code or give me an example?because I don't know much about AJAX

Comment: @Paresh Gami gave you the code. What ajax does is make a call to a file, for example php in your case and execute it. When everything is done, you get what the php echoed in your response and can play around with it. No need to reload the page.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot, I see that I have a lot to learn from now on!

Comment: How do you do this? Can you provide a code example?